# Correct way to flag "do my work for me" questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, homework

I am not a heavy user of StackOverflow due to various time constraints I face. As such, I sometimes see some very-low quality questions where OPs ask someone to get their work done (a.k.a. "I don't wanna code, can someone do it for me?") and have a hard time trying to figure how to handle them.

When I see such a thing, which is the correct way to flag for moderator attention? Should this kind of question be tolerated inside StackOverflow?

Comment: Homework isn't (alone) a reason to flag questions.

Comment: Downvoting is always a valid option for true "do my work for me" questions though.

Comment: I'm not sure why a moderator needs to get involved. It's either a good question or not; it shouldn't really matter if it's for school, work, hobby, etc. Also please see all the related questions to the right, as there has been much discussion on this in the past.

Comment: I downvoted this question, because I agree with the answer of @codeMagic: the reason for the question is not relevant.   What is relevant is whether it is a good question or not.  If it isn't, then the asker needs constructive feedback about what's wrong with it.  But "this is your homework" is not a reason in itself to flag.  If it were, it would be listed in the on-topic guide.

Comment: Homework questions where the poster has shown they have made a reasonable effort to understand the problem, and they have shown an attempt to solve it themselves by showing their source code are fine.  Homework questions where the poster simply asks the question and expects the community to solve it for them are cause for closure and if I am not mistaken should be raised with a custom flag. I do wish we had a close reason like "asking a homework question without showing reasonable effort" when voting to close or raising a flag.

Comment: @SlyRaskal Not sure why that is any different than a task I need to do for my job tomorrow. Actually I think that is even worse, because that guy is getting paid to do things the community does for them; in a lot of cases, the student is just trying to pass a course and may not give a rip about the language they're currently "learning"...

Comment: The reason definitely shouldn't matter. The effort is what is important.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I'm sorry, I'm not understanding the point you are trying to make, could you please clarify? The point I was just trying to get at is that homework questions are ok so long as the person has shown effort, just like any of the questions we address.  I was just trying to make it clear that closing a question just because it is a homework question isn't the right thing to do, that's all. Cheers.

Comment: @Sly and all I'm saying is that "do my code for me" questions are not welcome, regardless if they are homework, real work, etc. So there's no reason to even try to identify whether the question is a homework assignment from the asker's instructor, or a work assignment from PHB or Bill Lumbergh. This is one of the reasons the homework tag was deprecated, IIRC.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Well said. Thank you for clarifying, I totally agree with you on that.

Comment: @GreenAsJade I think I didn't explain well what I meant. In fact, I wanted to ask what to do with questions where the OP wants someone to give him/her the code done and working instead of clarifying his/her problem.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I didn't explain well. Instead, I meant questions where people want someone to code for them instead of making a minimum coding effort before asking.

Comment: I think there's a subtle difference about what you are concerned about than what you said.   In reality, you are concenred about whether someone is asking us to code for them.   Not whether it is homework, right?   It's still a problem if they don't make a minimal effort towards a professional or hobby project.  The homework aspect of it is common, but not relevant.   In the case where someone has asked us to code for them, the answer is easy.   "This question is interesting, but not suitable for SO. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic item 3."

Comment: You can also flag it as off-topic, checkbox 3 (which refers to minimal effort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be a homework tag but I think it was deprecated. I never understood the issue with it. I flag them like any other question. What is the difference if they are doing homework, working on a hobby project, or finishing a multi-million dollar app? We are here to help people with programming problems so that's what we should do.

So, if it is a terrible question, don't worry about *why* they need help. Instead, if it needs help comment, flag, downvote/upvote, etc... depending on the quality of the question.